# Holes in bucket

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, flow

Say a bucket of water has two holes equally close to the bottom, but one hole is larger.  As the water leaks out, the pressure at the holes decreases.  Should the amount of water leaking decrease proportionately at each hole--for example when the pressure is halved, would the amount of water leaking at EACH hole be half of what it previously was?

Comment: Hey vince, I am not sure if I get your point. What do you mean by the pressure at the holes decreases? The pressure at the hole is imposed by the atmospheric pressure. You could use a version of Torricelli's law to write down your thoughts: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/518309/245414 Furthermore you need to specify the ratio of the holes, the height and volume of the water column if you want a more detailed answer

Comment: By pressure at the holes decreasing, I presumed that the water pressure at the holes would automatically decrease as the water level above the holes decreases.  Actually, my question is really about proportions in general and not specific amounts of water.  Say, at first, the larger hole leaks twice the amount of water than the smaller hole.  As pressure decreases (the water level in the bucket decreases), would the larger hole continue leaking twice the quantity than does smaller hole?  In short, do the proportions remain constant?  Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The amount of liquid leaking through the two holes stays **constant** throughout the process and is **proportional to the area of the holes**.  You can estimate the ratio of the flow through the two holes using one-dimensional theory. This means it is only valid for small holes where the change of parameters across the hole is negligible.

---

Assume an open container ([hence everywhere the pressure $p_0$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/518309/245414)) with a constant cross-section $A_0$ and two holes with cross-sectional area $A_1$ and $A_2$ respectively.

With the **incompressible one-dimensional continuity equation** we find for the volume flux $Q_i = \frac{d V}{d t}$

$$ Q_0 = Q_1 + Q_2 $$

$$ A_0 u_0 = A_1 u_1 + A_2 u_2. $$

Apply **Bernoulli's equation** for a streamline from the water surface (or any other incompressible fluid) inside the container, that is sinking with velocity $u_0$, to the hole 1, where the water is exiting with velocity $u_1$,

$$ \frac{\rho u_0^2}{2} + \rho g h_0 + p_0 = \frac{\rho u_1^2}{2} + \rho g h_1 + p_0 $$

$$ \frac{u_0^2}{2} + g \underbrace{(h_0 - h_1)}_{h_{01}} = \frac{u_1^2}{2} \tag{1}\label{1}$$

and similarly for hole 2

$$ \frac{u_0^2}{2} + g \underbrace{(h_0 - h_2)}_{h_{02}} = \frac{u_2^2}{2}. \tag{2}\label{2} $$

If we subtract the two equations \eqref{2} - \eqref{1} we find

$$ g \underbrace{(h_1 - h_2)}_{h_{12}} = \frac{u_2^2}{2} - \frac{u_1^2}{2}. $$

As you can see if the centers of two holes are at the same height, meaning $h_{12} \approx 0$ the two velocities have to be equal. This result is independent of the liquid column and thus the flux of water through them $Q_i = A_i u_i$ at any given time only depends on the cross-sectional area.

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer also led me to this helpful related post:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/309267/how-does-the-size-of-the-hole-affect-the-exit-velocity?rq=1

Comment: @vince You are welcome. :)